Button hover causes overflow on mobile... what's the issue?
I’m working on a WordPress page that displays properly on desktop but runs into layout issues on mobile screens. Specifically, the button in the middle of my page overflows the container, making it look odd on smaller devices.
Here’s the relevant part of my CSS:
.btn {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
}

It works fine on desktop, but when I test it on mobile, the button seems too wide, and the padding looks off. I suspect it's related to the padding value, but I can’t seem to fix it.
I've tried using box-sizing: border-box; but that doesn’t seem to help either.
Any ideas on how to make it responsive or prevent it from overflowing?
Thanks!
HTML code of the page:
<div class="sharethis-inline-share-buttons"></div>
<p class="License autors_"><span>Under a Creative Commons </span><a class="anchor anchor-default" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener"><span class="anchor-text">license</span><svg focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 78 128" aria-label="Opens in new window" width="1em" height="1em" class="icon icon-arrow-up-right arrow-external-link"><path d="m4 36h57.07l-59.5 59.5 7.07 7.08 59.36-59.36v56.78h1e1v-74h-74z"></path></svg></a></p>
<div class="content">
    <p>The worldwide phenomenon that is Taylor Swift’s Eras Tour hasn’t just captured the hearts of her fans—it's been an economic force that has boosted local economies across multiple continents. From ticket sales and merchandise to hospitality and tourism, the financial ripple effect has been staggering.</p>

    <h2>The Unexpected Economic Windfall</h2>
    <p>Cities hosting the Eras Tour concerts have reported a dramatic increase in economic activity. Swifties are traveling far and wide to attend the concerts, and their spending isn’t limited to tickets. Hotel stays, dining, transportation, and local tourism have all surged in cities like Stockholm, Paris, and Sydney.</p>
    
    <h3>Record-Breaking Revenues</h3>
    <p>For example, Stockholm’s local government reported a 20% increase in tourism-related revenue during Swift’s concert weekend, with the hospitality sector alone gaining millions in additional sales. In Paris, hotels were booked out for weeks, and local businesses saw significant growth in foot traffic.</p>
    
    <h4>Travel and Accommodation Impact</h4>
    <p>Across Europe, Taylor Swift’s tour has become a catalyst for increased tourism. Fans from countries with more expensive tickets (like the U.S.) are traveling to European cities to enjoy both a concert and a vacation. This cross-continental travel has generated significant revenue for airlines, hotels, and even local attractions.</p>

    <p>According to a study from DashTickets, the top cities benefiting from the influx of concert-goers include:</p>
    
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Paris</strong>: 18% increase in hotel bookings during concert dates</li>
        <li><strong>Stockholm</strong>: 20% increase in tourism spending</li>
        <li><strong>Madrid</strong>: 15% rise in restaurant revenue</li>
    </ul>

    <p>While U.S. fans often pay as much as $2,000 for a single ticket, those attending the European leg of the tour report spending far less, even when factoring in travel costs. This has sparked a wave of international concert tourism, a phenomenon that’s significantly contributing to Europe’s local economies.</p>
    
    <h4>Global Comparison of Ticket Prices</h4>
    <p>Ticket prices for Taylor Swift’s concerts vary significantly by region, with European countries generally offering the most affordable options. Swift’s decision to play multiple shows in major European cities has helped bring down prices due to competitive ticket markets.</p>

    <button class="btn" id="ticketComparison">Compare Ticket Prices</button>

    <div class="price-comparison hidden" id="comparisonTable">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Ticket Price (USD)</th>
                <th>Local Impact</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Stockholm, Sweden</td>
                <td>$152</td>
                <td>20% Increase in Tourism Revenue</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paris, France</td>
                <td>$171</td>
                <td>18% Increase in Hotel Bookings</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Madrid, Spain</td>
                <td>$196</td>
                <td>15% Rise in Restaurant Revenue</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Styles for the Page -->
<style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .header {
        background-color: #ffdd00;
        color: black;
        padding: 30px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .content {
        width: 70%;
        margin: 30px auto;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 30px;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .btn {
        background-color: #007bff;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    /* Subtle CSS Bug: Padding issue on small screens (overflow on mobile due to large fixed width) */
    .btn:hover {
        background-color: #0056b3;
    }

    table {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table th, table td {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>


<script>
    const ticketComparisonBtn = document.getElementById('ticketComparison');
    const comparisonTable = document.getElementById('comparisonTable');

    ticketComparisonBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (comparisonTable.style.display === 'none') {
            comparisonTable.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            comparisonTable.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
</script>enter image description here


It seems ok to me, unless on really small resolutions. Either way, try adding width: 100% to the .btn

Not easy to reproduce, since it seems to be okay on chromes devtools on the mobile view port.
But here are some thought:


Maybee the words in the button do not break. You can style the text phrase extra. When I am remembering right, you can use this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.php


If you check on an iPhone, you can connect you mac and use there the dev tools from safari to see the relevant styles.


I might help that you do not use padding on the mobile view. You can use the full width by defining width: 100% and use text-align: center.



There is no issue with the blue button as I see. (If you are talking about the blue button)
I think the basic issue with this page is the large margin of content class
This way it seems too narrow in mobile devices.
you can use CSS Media Queries to apply smaller margin based on screen size.
